# jQuery run on document load

Tags: jquery

I have the following script that works well with the keyup function. I also want it to check the input value on load but cannot get this working.

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="30">
<p style="display:none;" id="error">Error</p>

<script>

$(function() {
    $("#test").keyup(function(){
        if( $(this).val() != '20') {
            $("#error").show();
            } else {
            $("#error").hide();
            }
    });
});

</script>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to raise the event when the page loads, which you can achieve in your case by using `keyup()` with no parameters. Also note that you can make your logic much more succinct by using `toggle()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test").keyup(function() {
    $('#error').toggle($(this).val() != '20');
  }).keyup();
});
```

```css
#error { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" value="30" />
<p id="error">Error</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a function you call *both* on load and on keyup, for instance:

```
$(function() {
    function checkTest(el) {
        if( el.val() != '20') {
            $("#error").show();
        } else {
            $("#error").hide();
        }
    }
    checkTest($("#test").keyup(function() {
        checkTest($(this));
    }));
});
```

Although you *could* do it by firing a synthetic `keyup` event at the element, I've never cared for that compared to simply calling the function yourself.

---

If this is a bit off-putting:

```
checkTest($("#test").keyup(function() {
    checkTest($(this));
}));
```

...you could separate them:

```
checkTest($("#test"));
$("#test").keyup(function() {
    checkTest($(this));
});
```

The former works because of jQuery's "chaining" API, so the return value of the call to `keyup` that sets up the handler is passed into `checkTest`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '20') {
      $("#error").show();
    } else {
      $("#error").hide();
    }
  });
  $("#test").keyup();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" value="30">
<p style="display:none;" id="error">Error</p>
```